# Is it bad to bind behaviours to document unconditionally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

The pagination controls on a page I am working on were being bound conditionally on there being more than 1 page. I don't like to see the following code in my projects,

```
if (pages > 1) {
  $('.some_class').bind('event', function() {});
}
```

because I feel it represents a disorganized coding style. I would put it on the same level as sprinkling `return` statements here and there rather than using control. I feel like binding events to globally available objects has no place in the local scope of a function call. So what I usually do is make two javascript files, for example: `pagination.js` and `pagination-controls.js`. In the one I have logic about building the html and displaying the the pagination controls. In the other I have statements like the following:

`$(document).on('click', '.pagination .next', function() {});`

Which fires regardless of whether there is a `$('.pagination .next')` element anywhere on the page. I like the way that feels: the website has behaviours and it only knows about ids and classes, not about instance variables in some local scope somewhere.

EDIT: this is definitely bad practice, as mentioned below. However:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document.

and the discussion on [direct and delegated](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) events is relevant. In particular I think the following describes my usage:

> By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document.

EDIT: So I guess now I'm wondering "is it bad to prefer binding behaviours to parent elements unconditionally over binding based on logic?" That's perhaps just a question of style, and my original question has been answered so I think I will accept the answer.

Comment: I'd say it's wasteful except, if you did have +1 pages, you'd be binding the event anyways, which means, you have to plan for that scenario when designing your app. In that light, I'm not sure it's really wasteful. I'd kind of look at it like reserving a huge block of memory for a desktop application before much of it is being used.

Comment: well, look at it this way. Every click event that happens on your page is going to be caught by that event, and the event.target is tested against the selector to see if it matches. If you used the first, it would not be adding additional processing on every click within your application.

Comment: Pick a JS framework and use it. jQuery naturally lends itself to a spaghetti mess with UI-related code at virtually all levels, there are some really good frameworks now which unwind this for you and provide solid convention for separating concerns.

Comment: I didn't initially understand that you were binding them to the top level document. Guess I should've read the entire question first. It really depends, I guess, on how many of these events you have, and if there is a chance they could start being utilized without a page refresh. (aka build some new DOM elements dynamically that would be targeted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is causing significant unnecessary overhead, and it is a "bad practice".

Binding your event handling to the top-level document object means that *every single click* that occurs on any element anywhere in your page will bubble up to the `document` object, where the event's target is checked to see if it matches `.pagination .next`.

In fact, the documentation itself recommends against your usage:

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. **Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents.**

So, you're misusing `on`. It's for binding directly to elements or to parent elements which may have dynamically created children, and you are meant to bind to the closest possible parent element. Binding to the document is certainly not meant to be the *only* way you handle events in your page.

Comment: Yeah and I guess it says "Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents." right there in the documentation.

Comment: If I bind the events to the `div` element that wraps the pagination controls, that would be more reasonable I think.

Comment: @Ziggy You should really just not be using `on`. It's for allowing events to be bound for elements that don't yet exist in the DOM; if your DOM is static, you should absolutely just be using `$('.some_class').bind...`.

Comment: Right: when I say "don't like to see" I mean, "don't think is organized". That looks to me about the same severity as a `return` statement in the middle of a long function.

On the other hand `$('.pagination-controls').on('click', function() {});` is maybe more reasonable?

[ I wrote this comment before I read the above one ]

Comment: `on` is the preferred method for binding events. I think I actually might be using it correctly, but with too heavy of a hand. Can you check out the discussion I linked to and give me your feedback. I feel like it is saying that the approach I describe in my comment above is acceptable.

Thanks for your attention @meagar !

Comment: What do you see in the linked discussion that you have questions about? The only example of delegation given in that section is one where delegation truly has an advantage over direct binding. In most of my applications, the application is made up primarily of self-contained widgets that are attached to a single element or multiple elements. When done that way, i usually just trigger events on the originating element so that i can attach additional functionality outside the scope of the widget. I rarely see a need for event delegation other than for tables and lists.

Comment: @meager `on` is fine for direct events.  It's only used as a delegate if you pass in the selector parameter into the `on` method.  In fact, `on` is the preferred method for both direct and delegate event handling since JQuery 1.7.

Comment: @meager yeah, can you remove that paragraph about misusing `on`? Then I will accept your answer, because basically you got it.

Comment: @Ziggy You *are* misusing `on`.

Comment: I mean that `on` is not strictly for "binding to parent elements which may have dynamically created children". Rather, "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document." So while I am certainly abusing `on`, I am not strictly speaking misusing it. You know what I mean? I'm not just splitting hairs: I don't want someone later to come and think that they should not use `on` for binding direct events.